can we set ConversationID for service bus trigger Azure v4 function c#? in ITelemetryInitializer
I m using Azure Function V4 Isolated Mode in c#. Its service bus Trigger function.
In message body I m already passing ConversationID.
I already added Telemetry.
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, AppSQLInsightsPropertiesTelemetryInitializer>();
  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
  services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights(); 

  public class AppSQLInsightsPropertiesTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
  {

      public AppSQLInsightsPropertiesTelemetryInitializer()
      {
              
      }
      public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
      {
          telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["ConversationID"] = "how i can get servicebus message ConversationID ";
      }
  }

how we can read service bus message ConversationID property and can add here for all logs which we are going to use in this Service bus trigger function.
any one have idea.

you can read the Service Bus message's ConversationID property, which is being sent.

The code below accesses the ConversationID property from the Service Bus message in an Azure Function Isolated C# function:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

public class ServiceBusTriggerFunction
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public ServiceBusTriggerFunction(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
    {
        _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
    }

    [Function(nameof(ServiceBusTriggerFunction))]
    public void Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("certificate122", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        var logger = context.GetLogger<ServiceBusTriggerFunction>();

        // Extract ConversationID from the message
        if (message.ApplicationProperties.TryGetValue("ConversationID", out var conversationId))
        {
            // Add ConversationID to telemetry properties
            _telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties["ConversationID"] = conversationId.ToString();
            // Log ConversationID
            logger.LogInformation("ConversationID1: {conversationId}", conversationId);
        }
        else
        {
            logger.LogInformation("ConversationID not found in message properties.");
        }

        
        logger.LogInformation("Custom Properties:");
        foreach (var property in message.ApplicationProperties)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("{Key}: {Value}", property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        
        logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
        logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
        logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

        
    }
}

Output:

Updated:

public class ServiceBusTriggerFunction
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;
    private string _conversationId;

    public ServiceBusTriggerFunction(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
    {
        _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
    }

    [Function(nameof(ServiceBusTriggerFunction))]
    public void Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("certificate122", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        var logger = context.GetLogger<ServiceBusTriggerFunction>();

        // Extract ConversationID from the message
        if (message.ApplicationProperties.TryGetValue("ConversationID", out var conversationId))
        {
            _conversationId = conversationId.ToString();
            // Log ConversationID
            logger.LogInformation("ConversationID: {conversationId}", _conversationId);
        }
        else
        {
            logger.LogInformation("ConversationID not found in message properties.");
        }

        // Log other message properties
        logger.LogInformation("Custom Properties:");
        foreach (var property in message.ApplicationProperties)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("{Key}: {Value}", property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        // Log other message properties
        logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
        logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
        logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

        // Track telemetry
        _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("ServiceBusMessageProcessed", new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "ConversationID", _conversationId }
        });
    }

    public string GetConversationID()
    {
        return _conversationId;
    }
}

public class AppSQLInsightsPropertiesTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly ServiceBusTriggerFunction _serviceBusTriggerFunction;

    public AppSQLInsightsPropertiesTelemetryInitializer(ServiceBusTriggerFunction serviceBusTriggerFunction)
    {
        _serviceBusTriggerFunction = serviceBusTriggerFunction;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var conversationId = _serviceBusTriggerFunction.GetConversationID();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(conversationId))
        {
            telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["ConversationID"] = conversationId;
        }
    }
}


i want to read inside AppSQLInsightsPropertiesTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
{
telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["ConversationID"] = "how i can get servicebus message ConversationID ";
}  here not at function level

Updated with AppSQLInsights

where you have register ServiceBusTriggerFunction  for DI?
public class AppSQLInsightsPropertiesTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
private readonly ServiceBusTriggerFunction _serviceBusTriggerFunction;

To register ServiceBusTriggerFunction for dependency injection (DI) in an Azure Function Isolated C# function, you can utilize the IServiceCollection

have you done cos it will give circular dependency? services.AddTransient();
: 'A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory'.
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime

Refer to dependency

Services.AddTransient(); : i already added this isolate v4 function
its giving 'A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory'.

we can inject other calsss and can use it rater then function it self

checking with above details
